# Destructor called implicitly every time I allocate with placement new

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have the following issue: I am using on my project custom Pool Allocator, and every time I am going to allocate any object with placement new, the destructor is also called on that object implicitly.

Here is the source code:

Test Object:

```
class Obj {
public:
    Obj(const std::string& s) {  
        std::cout << "Constructor Called" << std::endl; 
    }
    ~Obj() { 
        std::cout << "Destructor Called" << std::endl; 
    }

};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{

    void *pmemory;
    pmemory = malloc(ONEGIG_SIZE);

    PoolAllocator* poolAllocator =  new PoolAllocator(sizeof(Obj), __alignof(Obj), ONEGIG_SIZE, pmemory);
    Obj *obj1 = allocator::allocateNew(*poolAllocator, Obj("Hello")); //<-- const and dest is called

    //......

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the source code of Allocator :
AllocateNew function:

```
template <class T> T* allocateNew(Allocator& allocator, const T& t)
{
        return new (allocator.allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T(t);
}
```

Pool Allocator :

```
PoolAllocator::PoolAllocator(size_t objectSize, u8 objectAlignment, size_t size, void* mem)
        : Allocator(size, mem), _objectSize(objectSize), _objectAlignment(objectAlignment)
{
    ASSERT(objectSize >= sizeof(void*));

    //Calculate adjustment needed to keep object correctly aligned
    u8 adjustment = pointer_math::alignForwardAdjustment(mem, objectAlignment);

    _free_list = (void**)pointer_math::add(mem, adjustment);

    size_t numObjects = (size-adjustment)/objectSize;

    void** p = _free_list;

    //Initialize free blocks list
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numObjects-1; i++)
    {
        *p = pointer_math::add(p, objectSize );
        p = (void**) *p;
    }

    *p = nullptr;
}

PoolAllocator::~PoolAllocator()
{
    _free_list = nullptr;
}

void* PoolAllocator::allocate(size_t size, u8 alignment)
{
    ASSERT(size == _objectSize && alignment == _objectAlignment);

    if(_free_list == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    void* p = _free_list;

    _free_list = (void**)(*_free_list);

    _used_memory += size;
    _num_allocations++;

    return p;
}

void PoolAllocator::deallocate(void* p)
{
    *((void**)p) = _free_list;

    _free_list = (void**)p;

    _used_memory -= _objectSize;
    _num_allocations--;
}
```

It seems that the destructor is called after the return o p in allocate method in Pool Allocator! Anyone can explain why this is happening ?

Comment: I'd say you should add debug printing to *all* constructors. Something tells me that the extra destructor call you're seeing actually happens on a tempoprary, possibly here: `Obj *obj1 = allocator::allocateNew(*poolAllocator, Obj("Hello"));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... every time i am going to allocate any object with placement new, the destructor is also called on that object implicitly

No, the destructor is also called on *an* object. You're just assuming - incorrectly - that the destroyed object is the one allocated in your pool.

Intuitively, since your `allocateNew` function takes a const ref to *something* as an argument, that *something* must exist, which means it was created before anything was allocated in your pool.

In detail though,

```
Obj *obj1 = allocator::allocateNew(*poolAllocator, Obj("Hello"));
```

will:

1. `Obj("Hello")`

   create a new anonymous temporary object, with the `std::string` constructor which will log the message you saw
2. `allocateNew(Allocator& allocator, const T& t)`

   pass a const ref to that anonymous temporary into your `allocateNew` function.
3. `return new (...) T(t)`

   placement-new *another* object in your pool, using the implicitly-generated copy constructor *which does not log anything*
4. return a pointer to the new object allocated in your pool
5. destroy the anonymous temporary when it goes out of scope at the end of the statement.

If you want an accurate picture of what's happening, implement logging versions *all* constructor (and assignment operator) variants.

If you want to avoid the temporary object + copy, pass a `T&& t` and move-construct into the pool.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
Obj *obj1 = allocator::allocateNew(*poolAllocator, Obj("Hello"));
```

creates a temporary of type `Obj`  (from `Obj("Hello")`), and passes it by reference to `allocator::allocateNew()`.

Within the function

```
template <class T> T* allocateNew(Allocator& allocator, const T& t)
{
        return new (allocator.allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T(t);
}
```

receives that temporary object as `t`, and the `new (allocator.allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T(t)` creates a copy of it (in the memory provided by `allocator.allocate()` with the supplied arguments.   This uses the copy constructor, which your code is not tracking.

When `allocator::allocateNew()` returns, and before control passes to the next statement, the temporary is destroyed.

The copy created inside `allocateNew()` continues to exist.

The destructor is not being called implicitly on the object that results from the `new` expression.   It is being called for the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

This: 'Obj("Hello")' creates a temporary which is used to copy initialize another object in your placement new. After that the temporary is destroyed by calling its destructor.